# How to I add additional symlinks on a homebrew formula?

Tags: homebrew, mc

I have at least one application that is installing executables in another folder than its `{{prefix}}/bin`, one like `{{[prefix}}/libexec/mc/mcwrapper.sh`.

I know that brew does symlink all the files from `bin/` automatically, without needing any configuration. Check `brew edit mc` and you will not see any code for creating the symlinks.

Now the question is how do I tell mc to also symlink few other scripts so I can have them in the path?

Answer (score 2):

Formulas are Ruby scripts and you can use [ln_s](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/fileutils/rdoc/FileUtils.html#ln_s-method) or [ln_sf](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/fileutils/rdoc/FileUtils.html#ln_sf-method) methods to create symlinks.

`ln_s SOURCE, "#{HOMEBREW_PREFIX}/some/custom/target", :force => true`

or shorter using using alias `ln_sf`

`ln_sf SOURCE, "#{HOMEBREW_PREFIX}/some/custom/target"`

Replace `SOURCE` with your file or directory you want to symlink.

From the Ruby docs:

> ln_s(old, new, options = {})
>
> Creates a symbolic link new which points to old. If new already exists
>   and it is a directory, creates a symbolic link new/old. If new already
>   exists and it is not a directory, raises Errno::EEXIST. But if :force
>   option is set, overwrite new.